# Custom Title Font For ASP.NET Chart Helper

Tags: c#, asp.net, charts, fonts

I've been searching on how to change the font of the title in my charts on my asp.net project and I couldn't find a way to change the font with the implementation of the chart in my code ( controller code ) :

```
public ActionResult Foo()
{
      var model = new ChartViewModel
      {
           Chart = FooGetChart() //System.Web.Helpers.Chart
      };
      return View(model);
}
```

FooGetChart function =

```
return new Chart(1200, 600, ChartTheme.Vanilla3D)
                .AddLegend("foo")
                .AddTitle("foo")//This is the font I want to change
                .AddSeries(
                    name: "foo",
                    chartType: "Pie",
                    xValue: groupsList.ToArray(),
                    yValues: groupsCount.ToArray());
```

On my view :

```
@Model.Chart.Write(format: "png")
```

I'm sure it's something simple that I can't manage to find somehow, or maybe I have to recode the whole thing.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to provide your own custom XML theme file:

[image]

**MyTheme4.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Chart>
  <Titles>
    <Title Name="Title1" ForeColor="LightBlue"  Font="Comic Sans, 32pt, style=Italic">
    </Title>
  </Titles>
</Chart>
```

**Chart:**

```
return new Chart(width: 600, height: 300, themePath: "MyTheme4.xml")
            .AddTitle("My Custom Chart Title", "Title1") //This is the font I want to change
            .AddSeries(
                chartType: "Pie",
                xValue: new[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 },
                yValues: new[] {10,20,30,40,50});
```

Comment: Thanks! I decided to switch to chartjs instead but thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Title title = Chart1.Titles.Add("Test");
       title.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Arial", 16, FontStyle.Bold);

Comment: System.Web.Helpers.Chart does not have a definition for .Titles, only .AddTitle

Comment: model.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Arial", 16, FontStyle.Bold);

Comment: The ChartViewModel code is : using System.Web.Helpers;

namespace ViewModel
{
    public class ChartViewModel
    {
        public Chart Chart { get; set; }
    }
}

so that is not working